# How do I use my MIDI keyboard with Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, midi

I just got a MIDI to USB cable in the mail today so I got everything hooked up and went to MIDI devices on audacity and I didn't find it. I have no clue if I'm missing a driver or something like that

Let me know if you know how to fix this, Thanks!

Comment: Does something show up in the output of `amidi -l` or `arecordmidi -l`?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to use JACK audio connection as shown

[image: screenshot]